# How to add justify-content:space between only to 2nd and 3rd child

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Is it possible to add justify-content: space-between only to 2nd and 3rd child of a div?
I don't want to make another parent around them, because that will broke my previous style.
I need to have structure like this:

```css
.wrapper{
     display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container-1">content 1</div>
    <div class="container-2">content 2</div>
    <!-- add space here -->
    <div class="container-3">content 3</div>
</div>
```

And my final result needs to look like this:

[image]

Maybe using nth child or something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.wrapper{
     display:flex;
}

.container-3{
     margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container-1">content 1</div>
    <div class="container-2">content 2</div>
    <!-- add space here -->
    <div class="container-3">content 3</div>
</div>
```

This css will push your container-3 to the right and add available space in between